# Proper way to make custom component containing other components

Tags: delphi, firemonkey, custom-component

I want make my own simple component which contains other components. It looks like:

```
TTag = class(TLayout)
private
    _line: TLine;
    _label: TLabel;
    _background: TRoundRect;
    _button: TLabel;
public
    constructor Create(AOwner: TComponent); override;
end;
```

When I put this component on form everything is ok and my form structure looks like:
[image]

but after Delphi IDE reopen it's looks like:

[image]

How add sub-components to avoid this strange behavior?

Comment: Just set Stored := False for all the sub components

Answer (score 8, accepted):

That is a typical case for [SetSubComponent](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Tokyo/en/System.Classes.TComponent.SetSubComponent):

> Call SetSubComponent to indicate whether this component is a
>   subcomponent. A subcomponent is a component whose Owner is a component
>   other than the form or data module in which it resides. Unless such a
>   component calls SetSubComponent with IsSubComponent set to True, its
>   published properties will not be saved to the form file.

For each of your sub-components make a call to `SetSubComponent(True)` in your constructor.